# react-native remove default android permissions

Tags: android, react-native, android-permissions

I created a new react-native app with `react-native init ProjectName`.

I then removed `android.permission.INTERNET` and `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` from the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

With `cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease` I created a new APK.

Then I analyzed it with `aapt dump badging app-release-unsigned.apk`. Important output:

```
uses-permission: name='android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
```

Where do those permissions come from? And how can I remove them? I don't use any of them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

In **Manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="${permissionName}" tools:node="remove"/>
```

i.e.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" tools:node="remove"/>
```

Do the same for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem while building the release apk. I found an article on medium, which describes how to remove the permission by editing the gradle file and not the AndroidManifest.xml. Have a look at this: https://medium.com/@applification/fixing-react-native-android-permissions-9e78996e9865

Hope this helps ;)